# Is there a way to print the prime number itself and the overall count after having filtered non-prime?

Tags: arrays, c, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have the code below and it's annotated. It is essentially based on 'Sieve of Eratosthenes.' I am modifying it to have the remaining prime numbers printed and counted in the last for loop of the code. However, the output is '1There are 1 primes.'

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 50000

int main(void) {
    int i, mult, count, count2;
    int flag[SIZE + 1];

    count = 0;
    count2 = 0;

    //sets up all numbers
    for (i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++) {
        flag[i] = 1;
        //printf("%d",flag[i]);
    }

    //step 1: selects the prime number
    for (i = 2; i <= SIZE; ++i) {
        if (flag[i] == 1)
            ++count;
        mult = i;

        //step 2: filters out numbers multiple of that prime number in step 1
        while (mult <= SIZE) {
            flag[mult] = 0;
            mult = mult + i;
        }
    }

    //Now that the non-prime numbers have been filtered, this then prints the number and counts the prime numbers
    for (i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++) {
        if (flag[i] == 1) {
            ++count2;
            printf("%d", i);
        }
    }

    printf("There are %d primes. \n", count2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to print a blank line after your last loop to separate it from the count line. But it sounds like your sieve is broken and you only think 1 is prime.

Comment: In your sieve you're marking i as non-prime. That's wrong: i might be prime. You should mark 2*i, 3*i etc. as non-prime.

Comment: you're deleting you're prime number when you initialize i to mult. You should replace `mult = i;` with `mult = i + i;`

Comment: Please learn away with the one-based array indexing, you will be very alone in doing that otherwise (and no one else will be able to properly use your code). Array indexes are *zero* based.

Comment: The line `mult = i;` should be `mult = i * i`. That line, and the following `while` loop should be inside the body of the `if (flag[i] == 1)` statement (along with `++count;`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that is true, but here it would perverse to represent, say, `7` by `6`. When the primality of `i` has been determined, that is recorded at `flag[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second **for** loop, you start with:

```
mult = i;
```

and then in the **while** that is just after you set:

```
flag[mult] = 0;
```

In essence you say this number is not a prime.

If you replace the line **mult = i** with:

```
mult = i + i ;
```

Then your program is working.

Comment: You can start with `mult = i * i;` Consider the prime `7`. The `14`, `21` etc have already  been marked off (from the smaller factors) so you can start at `7 * 7`.